# Jhipster TS2440: Import declaration conflicts with local declaration of 'I

Tags: jhipster

Getting the following error while server startup in jhipster:

ERROR in .../webapp/app/shared/model/category-model.model.ts(1,10):
TS2440: Import declaration conflicts with local declaration of 'ICategoryModel'.
[INFO] npm ERR! code ELIFECYCLE
[INFO] npm ERR! errno 2

```
import { ICategoryModel } from 'app/shared/model/category-model.model';

export interface ICategoryModel {
  subCategories?: ICategoryModel[];
  parentCategory?: ICategoryModel;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

It seems to be same issue as https://github.com/jhipster/generator-jhipster/issues/11549 it has been fixed  on master branch and will be part of next release 6.9.0

In the meantime, you can just delete the import statement from category-model.model.ts